# Folder permissions on CD or DVD disc

Tags: permissions, pdf, dvd

I understand folder permissions on a hard disc, but now I have a client that wants folder permissions on a removable CD or DVD disc.  The disc has a .pdf file that is a service manual.  In the manual are all the appropriate warnings to keep the legal department happy.  From the manual, users can link to view video files about the service being performed.  These links happen on pages that have all the proper warnings on them that they see before linking to the video.  Now they have figured out that the folder on the CD or DVD can be opened without going through the .pdf file, so the videos can be viewed without the warning messages.  SO, is there any way to restrict a user from opening a folder on a CD or DVD, but allow the .pdf file to link to the video files in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Perhaps.

There are third-party tools and programs that can protect information on a disk, but they generally require that you install a program or at least run a program on the viewers computer to make the data available, and then it would be just as available as if you'd given them the disk, which you have.

Once you have written the data to those disks, all of the information on the disks is visible to anyone who can view any of the data on those disks.

An alternate method would be to host the videos on a website that requires you to go through the legalese, and then the PDF just links to the videos on the website. This, of course, requires the viewers to have fast internet access.

An additional alternate method is to place the video warnings are the beginning of each video, and not just in the PDF file and links. This, of course, can then be fast-forwarded past, but it was still there and the viewer had to intend to fast forward in order to get past the legalese.